# Neodymium magnet pole reversal?

Tags: electromagnetism

I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXVmEPU1L1k) which showed a Neodymium magnet being cut in half, what i expected to see was the two halves snap together due to aligned poles as shown in the image below,

[image: cut magnets]

but what actually seems to have happened in the video is the two halves strongly repelled each other as if the poles formed were both the same charge. Why didn't they simply recombine? Did the poles reverse somehow?

Comment: the magnet was broken in the opposite sense, along its length.